# Is is possible to record my WPF control to a movie?

Tags: wpf, video, record

I have an application where it is possible to load new content through usercontrols. Some of these usercontrols have distinct features such as pulsing buttons and other kind of animations. What i want to do is provide the user with a small video that shows the usercontrol in action.

The user adds usercontrols through an ASP.NEt MVC  application so i dont think its possible to just "play" the usercontrol. I expect to be able to playback the video using silverlight.

Is this even possible? I am able to create a screenshot, but from there to creating a small video (max 10 secs) seems hard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can: http://blogs.msdn.com/saveenr/archive/2008/09/22/wpf-xaml-saving-an-animation-as-an-avi-video-file.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have used [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) to great effect in the past.